# Short Volatility

Tags: volatility

Being net short options is an obvious case of being short volatility. But what other investments are "functionally" short volatility? Is long equities long or short volatility? Is short Apple long or short volatility? Does a yield curve trade have a volatility component? If you are in the carry trade, short one currency to be long another currency to capture interest rate differentials, do you have a defined volatility position?

Answer (score 3):

The currency carry trade is generally said to be short volatility. The reason is that when [currency] volatility rises, the carry trade suffers, and when volatility falls, the carry trade does well.  You can do a regression of carry trade profits vs volatility [either currency volatility, or even just the VIX as a proxy for all volatility]; or just anecdotally it seems that the big losses are in months when there is a lot of turmoil, like in late 2007 if I remember well.

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts about this very interesting question:

- A long position in a diversified stock index (I would not bet that this is true for all single stocks) quite surely results in a short position in volatility. The correlation here is something like $-0.7$ (as books tell, this is of course just an indication.
- Therefore I have observed the phenomenon that a call is less of a long position in volatility than a put. If the stock price rises the call appreciates in value but as vol tends to decrease the move is dampened. For puts a decrease in price tends to be accompanied by rising vola and the price rises even more.
- In times where duration is negatively correlated to risky assets (especially stocks) - usually a risk-on/risk-off period it tends to be positively correlated with (stock) volatility. Thus something like Bund or Treasury futures long correlates with stock vola long (with a beta very different from 1).
- Carry trades work if "everything" (yield curve shapes, differentials, ...) stay the same. In times of high volatility (as Alex C writes) such trades can suffer.
- For a Euro investor a short in USD is like long stocks resp. short volatility. In times of (stock) volatility the USD tends to rise against the EUR. Then being long USD helps.